# Exception when returning list of objects with servicestack

Tags: c#, .net, json, servicestack, dto

I am attempting to get ServiceStack to return a list of objects to a C# client, but I keep getting this exception:

```
"... System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type definitions should start with a '{' ...."
```

The model I am trying to return:

```
public class ServiceCallModel
{

    public ServiceCallModel()
    {
        call_uid = 0;
    }

    public ServiceCallModel(int callUid)
    {
        this.call_uid = callUid;
    }

    public int call_uid { get; set; }
    public int store_uid { get; set; }

    ...... <many more properties> ......

    public bool cap_expense { get; set; }
    public bool is_new { get; set; }
    // An array of properties to exclude from property building 
    public string[] excludedProperties = { "" };
}
```

The response:

```
public class ServiceCallResponse
{
    public List<ServiceCallModel> Result { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; } //Where Exceptions get auto-serialized
}
```

And the service:

```
public class ServiceCallsService : Service 
{
    // An instance of model factory
    ModelFactory MyModelFactory = new ModelFactory(); 

    public object Any(ServiceCallModel request)
    {
        if (request.call_uid != 0)
        {
            return MyModelFactory.GetServiceCalls(request.call_uid); 
        } else { 
            return MyModelFactory.GetServiceCalls() ; 
        }
    }
}
```

The client accesses the service with:

```
        JsonServiceClient client = new ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.JsonServiceClient("http://172.16.0.15/");
        client.SetCredentials("user", "1234");
        client.AlwaysSendBasicAuthHeader = true;
        ServiceCallResponse response = client.Get<ServiceCallResponse>("/sc");
```

The "model factory" class is a DB access class which returns a list. Everything seems to work just fine when I access the service through a web browser. The JSON returned from the service starts:

```
"[{"call_uid":70...."
```

And ends with:

```
"....false,"is_new":true}]"
```

My question is, what here might be causing serialization/deserialization to fail?

**Solution**

Thanks to the answer from mythz, I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong. My misunderstanding was in exactly how many DTO types there are and exactly what they do. In my mind I had them sort of merged together in some incorrect way. So now as I understand it:

Object to return (In my case, called "ServiceCallModel": The actual class you wish the client to have once ServiceStack has done its job. In my case, a ServiceCallModel is a key class in my program which many other classes consume and create.

Request DTO: This is what the client sends to the server and contains anything related to making a request. Variables, etc.

Response DTO: The response that the server sends back to the requesting client. This *contains* a single data object (ServiceCallModel), or in my case... a list of ServiceCallModel.

Further, exactly as Mythz said, I now understand the reason for adding "IReturn" to the request DTO is so the client will know precisely what the server will send back to it. In my case I am using the list of ServiceCallModel as the data source for a ListView in Android. So its nice to be able to tell a ListViewAdapter that "response.Result" is in fact already a useful list.

Thanks Mythz for your help.

Comment: `public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus` try renaming the object to something like `MyResponseStatus`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error:

```
Type definitions should start with a '{'
```

Happens when the shape of the JSON doesn't match what it's expecting, which for this example:

```
ServiceCallResponse response = client.Get<ServiceCallResponse>("/sc");
```

The client is expecting the Service to return a `ServiceCallResponse`, but it's not clear from the info provided that this is happening - though the error is suggesting it's not.

#### Add Type Safety

Although it doesn't change the behavior, if you specify types in your services you can assert that it returns the expected type, e.g Change `object` to `ServiceCallResponse`, e.g:

```
public ServiceCallResponse Any(ServiceCallModel request)
{
    ...
}
```

To save clients guessing what a service returns, you can just specify it on the Request DTO with:

```
public class ServiceCallModel : IReturn<ServiceCallResponse>
{
    ...
}
```

This lets your clients have a more succinct and typed API, e.g:

```
ServiceCallResponse response = client.Get(new ServiceCallModel());
```

instead of:

```
ServiceCallResponse response = client.Get<ServiceCallResponse>("/sc");
```

See the [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) and [C# Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) docs for more info.

Comment: Thanks much, I've summarized the solution you lead me to below my question